# Force reference to be cached based on programmer foreknowledge

Tags: rust

I know for my use case that a particular reference will be referenced a lot. Is it possible to tell the compiler to cache it in L1?

Comment: The compiler does not determine cache locations. The CPU does.

Comment: Have you compiled the code and inspected the assembly yet? It's quite plausible that the compiler may have put the referent even closer, e.g. in a register or two, depending on its size and such.

Answer (score 4):

For at least x86[-64] and aarch64, there are cache hinting instructions exposed to Rust, e.g. [`core::arch::x86_64::_mm_prefetch`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/core/arch/x86_64/fn._mm_prefetch.html). On current nightly, [`intrinsics::prefetch_read_data`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/intrinsics/fn.prefetch_read_data.html)/`prefetch_write_data` abstract over these.

You *probably* don’t need to use them. Caching things that are referenced a lot is what the CPU already tries to do by default.

Comment: Worth noting that prefetching is not a "one and done" thing; it will trigger a load into the cache but that doesn't mean it will stay there. If your workload means this highly referenced data is continually kicked out of L1, tuning where to make the prefetch calls will take some finesse (call it too early and the value may get kicked out again before being used, call it too late and you may miss cycles waiting for the value being fetched).

Comment: Also, this is not needed if the value "will be referenced a lot" because the CPU will in most likelyhood already keep the value in cache. This is only needed if there are a lot of values which are used rarely, and so are likely not in cache when you want them, but when you can anticipate that the value will be needed soon.

Comment: But note that modern CPUs are already capable of analyzing memory usage patterns (e.g. when you're looping through an array) and prefetching upcoming values without waiting for the code to try to access them → **As with all performance related issues: profile, _profile_ and profile to make sure that the bottleneck is where you think it is and that your changes actually improve performance.**